# finding last value with matching row in excel

Tags: excel

I want to find out last occurrence of particular value and if it is there apply some formula.

```
Machine Starttime             Alert
a       10/19/2016 12:16:15   S
a       10/19/2016 12:18:15   E
a       10/19/2016 12:19:20   S
b       10/19/2016 12:21:45   S
b       10/19/2016 12:21:48   S
b       10/19/2016 12:21:55   E
a       10/19/2016 12:23:15   S
a       10/19/2016 12:27:30   E
```

Machine column will have machine name, Starttime is log time of that particular event and alert can be start of End.

I need output like following:

```
Machine Starttime   Alert   Difference
a   10/19/2016 12:16:15 S   
a   10/19/2016 12:18:15 E   120
a   10/19/2016 12:19:20 S   
b   10/19/2016 12:21:45 S   
b   10/19/2016 12:21:48 S   
b   10/19/2016 12:21:55 E   10
a   10/19/2016 12:23:15 S   
a   10/19/2016 12:27:30 E   490
```

Difference will be populated only in case of E and there is corresponding start event for that machine, if there are more than one start event then pick first one. I just want to understand if it is possible with just excel formula(without macro)? if yes, how?

I already tried it using index function without success

```
=IF(C3="E",MATCH(A3,A2:$A$2,0),"")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible but it is not easy. You have to use an array formula to solve this. The formula would be:

```
=IF(C2="S","",(B2-MIN(IF($A$2:A2=A2,IF($C$2:C2="S",IF(ROW($A$2:A2)>MAX(IF(ROW($A$2:A2)<ROW(A2),IF($A$2:A2=A2,IF($C$2:C2="E",ROW($A$2:A2))))),$B$2:B2)))))*86400)
```

First data row is 2, column A has the machine names, column B the log times, column c the "S"/"E". Put the formula in column D in the first data row and push CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to make it an array formula. You should see `{}` around the formula now.
Copy the cell (CTRL+C) and paste it into all rows **except** the row where the formula is already in.

If you need any more help, place a comment.

Comment: It is giving wrong value if there are two consecutive "E". It is possible to have two "E" sometimes, in that case we need to ignore second "E"

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with some complicated array formula, but a helper formula can make it easier to distinguish the groups. For example in `D2`:

```
= ( ABS(N(D1))+($A2<>$A1) ) * IF(C2="S",1,-1)
```

and the final Index + Match formula next to it in `E2` :

```
=IF($C2="E", ROUND( ($B2 - INDEX($B$2:$B$9, MATCH(ABS($D2),$D$2:$D$9,0) ) )*24*60*60,0),"")
```

With your sample data, it should result in something like this:

```
A       B                   C       D       E
-----------------------------------------------------------
Machine Starttime           Alert   Group   Index+Match
a       10/19/2016 12:16    S        1      
a       10/19/2016 12:18    E       -1      120
a       10/19/2016 12:19    S        1      
b       10/19/2016 12:21    S        2      
b       10/19/2016 12:21    S        2      
b       10/19/2016 12:21    E       -2      10
a       10/19/2016 12:23    S        3      
a       10/19/2016 12:27    E       -3      255
```

Comment: why group for last two row is 3? it should be 1 as it is same machine. there is typo in my question, I need 490 as time difference in last row. i.e. difference between earlierst start buttion(which is not close yet) and last end button.